# Optimize an algorithm to find multiple specific substrings of a string

Tags: c++, optimization, substring

I'm new to C++ coding and just started solving competitive programming problems. I want to solve the following task: https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1620.
I want to find a substring of a string. The problem is that the code below is slow and I fail the submission by getting the "*time limit exceeded*" "error". What can I do to speed up the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    stringstream ss;
    string m;
    char prob[100000];
    char substring[1000];
    int howManyCases = 0;
    int numberOfTests = 0; 

    cin >> numberOfTests;
    cin.ignore();
    while(numberOfTests--)
    {
        cin >> prob >> howManyCases;

        while(howManyCases--)
        {
            cin >> substring;
            if (strstr(prob,substring)) {
                ss << 'y' << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                ss << 'n' << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    m = ss.str();
    cout << m;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *what can i do to speed up the code?* -- Scrap the code, and research algorithms such as [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm).

Comment: your character arrays are too small. When the input is 100000 characters for `prob` or `1000` for the substring to be found then there is no space for the null terminator in those arrays. Then calling `strstr` causes undefined behavior. One possibility is that `strstr` keeps looping forever, because it wont find the terminator of the strings. I wouldnt bet on it, but this alone might explain why you get a timeout

Comment: [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search).  The second thing is that questions you get from those competitive programming websites are worded so that there will always be a naive approach to answer the question (such as your attempt).  The issue is that the naive approach is easy to write, but will almost always fail due to time-out and/or input size.  The goal of those questions is to see if you can do the research in finding the non-naive solution, i.e. use a better searching algorithm such as the ones I already mentioned.

Comment: fwiw, my conclusion in above comment was wrong. `cin >> prob` wont read "too many" characters into the array and there wont be UB, but in any case your arrays are too small by 1 character

Answer (score 0):

i would make you of `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::string parent_string = "some string lala";
std::string sub_string = "lala";
auto found = parent_string.find(sub_string);
```

it will return iterator to where substring is. Then I wou;d use this clause:

```
if (found != std::string::npos) std::cout << "y\n";
else std::cout << "n\n";
```

If there is no limitation to the use of standard libraries, It's always a better choice to use it instead of creating your own algorithms (that may not handle some special cases you won't think of ).
Also, swap those huge ugly `c-style arrays` to `std::string`.

Comment: why would you expect this to be any faster than `strstr` ?